# How to use Google Plus access token on backend side

Tags: php, android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm working on a mobile app based even on google plus api .

We have a client part formed by device such android or IOS that consuming JSon from a php server side back end.

Actually we obtain an access token from the client side, but when we try to pass it on the beck end side we can't handle the request and we got just mine data (even with other login in different pc) or bad errors...

wich is the right flow?

why I can't simply invoke setAccessToken() on $client obj with the passed token?

I try to put out some details:

we have an android client that i don't know how make the login but he can send me a valid Token by invoking mine php backend function.

here is the code of my php backend:

```
    require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
    function getGooglePlusStream($tokenId)

  {

    $client = new Google_Client();


    $client->setApplicationName("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setRedirectUri('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me','                            https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.medi a.upload'));
   $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

$tokenazzo='{"access_token":"","token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600,"id_token":$tokenId,"   
refresh_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx","created":1390214181}';

   $client->setAccessToken($tokenazzo);
   $client->authenticate();

   $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');

   ......... `
```

Comment: in client side we have an approach like that  [GPLUS ](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app)

Comment: is that one the right approach? [gplus](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow?hl=eng)